# Logging Virus Definition Updates for MS Security Essentials in The Security Event Log

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I would like to log a security in event in Windows 7 whenever the Microsoft Security Essentials 2 virus definition files are updates, deleted, or changed. I was expecting to do this with an Audit setting on one of the MS Security Essentials folders but I wasn't sure which one and how to avoid getting swamped with messages.

What folder or files should I audit to track definition updates (or corruption) in the security events or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support provided the following response to this question:

> As of now, MSE does not have any such features or user commands that
>   can be used to monitor the changes to its files. However, it protects
>   itself by locking those files and denying access to third party
>   programs or even the user.
>
> Your audit log to monitor C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   Antimalware\Definition Updates folder will take care of the
>   requirement. And this is what our Research Team suggest and recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.  instead use the Windows Update log (`%SystemRoot%\WindowsUpdate.log`)instead.

Comment: But then is there no way to log if another user or program purposely replaces virus definitions?

Comment: @Steve what do you mean?